# HDD keeps locking to read-only; Cannot isolate cause of disk errors

Tags: files, filesystems, lvm, hard-disk

**The problem**: After running with no issues for several months, one of my HDDs will lock into read-only mode seemingly at-random when in use. This can often be fixed by cycling power to the hard drives.

It is also worth noting that sometimes when idle the machine will initiate some kind of a scan, which makes a loud, repetitive sound of the HDD spinning up and doing non-continuous reads.

**The setup**: 2x6TB HDDs connected to a Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian) with SATA->USB3 bridges. The two drives are spanned together into one LVM volume, called `nas-nas`. The power connection of the HDDs are connected to an external PSU, so the problematic behavior is not due to drawing too much current over USB.

```
# lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0  5.5T  0 disk 
└─nas-nas   254:0    0 10.9T  0 lvm  /mnt/nas
sdb           8:16   0  5.5T  0 disk 
└─nas-nas   254:0    0 10.9T  0 lvm  /mnt/nas
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.7G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.5G  0 part /
```

*Update*: USB information. The two drives are connected via USB3 to a hub, and then connected to a USB3 port on the RPi.

```
# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB3.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Troubleshooting thus far**:

- Running smartmontools on `/dev/sdb` results in no errors.
- Running smartmontools on `/dev/sda/` results in the following errors:

```
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 ff ff ff 0f  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0fffffff = 268435455

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 da 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:34:37.965  READ DMA EXT
  25 da 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:34:37.866  READ DMA EXT
  25 da 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:34:34.622  READ DMA EXT
  25 da 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:34:34.601  READ DMA EXT
  25 da 08 ff ff ff 4f 00      05:34:34.601  READ DMA EXT
```

The above error repeats multiple times; the listed registers and LBA address are always the same.

```
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       40%      2726         -
# 2  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%      2699         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2699         -
```

Given these errors, I tried to follow the directions written [here](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/BadBlockHowto) on how to correct the badblocks errors, however there were no pertinent entries in `/var/log/messages` and it did not have any read/write errors in the listed blocks on that disk:

```
# export i=268435445
# while [ $i -lt 268435465 ]; do echo $i; dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=512 count=1 skip=$i; let i+=1; done
268435445
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.23521 s, 2.2 kB/s
268435446
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000614278 s, 833 kB/s
268435447
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000601148 s, 852 kB/s
268435448
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.00667811 s, 76.7 kB/s
268435449
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000606686 s, 844 kB/s
268435450
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.0005965 s, 858 kB/s
268435451
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000601019 s, 852 kB/s
268435452
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000597833 s, 856 kB/s
268435453
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000597778 s, 857 kB/s
268435454
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000447834 s, 1.1 MB/s
268435455
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000444796 s, 1.2 MB/s
268435456
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000975908 s, 525 kB/s
268435457
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000445574 s, 1.1 MB/s
268435458
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000459315 s, 1.1 MB/s
268435459
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000816092 s, 627 kB/s
268435460
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000470667 s, 1.1 MB/s
268435461
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000437908 s, 1.2 MB/s
268435462
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000448389 s, 1.1 MB/s
268435463
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000474222 s, 1.1 MB/s
268435464
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000862722 s, 593 kB/s
```

Additionally, when the drive locks up into read-only state, the following is logged in `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
Jul 23 03:26:58 raspberrypi kernel: [109352.963651] EXT4-fs (dm-0): error count since last fsck: 69
Jul 23 03:26:58 raspberrypi kernel: [109352.963680] EXT4-fs (dm-0): initial error at time 1688029202: __ext4_find_entry:1665: inode 242745346
Jul 23 03:26:58 raspberrypi kernel: [109352.963697] EXT4-fs (dm-0): last error at time 1689762775: __ext4_get_inode_loc_noinmem:4418: inode 242745345: block 1941962784
Jul 23 03:28:32 raspberrypi kernel: [109447.265453] usb 2-1.3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jul 23 03:29:09 raspberrypi kernel: [109484.133832] usb 2-1.3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jul 23 03:30:12 raspberrypi kernel: [109547.618426] usb 2-1.3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jul 23 03:30:47 raspberrypi kernel: [109582.434776] usb 2-1.3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jul 23 03:31:57 raspberrypi kernel: [109652.071255] usb 2-1.3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jul 23 03:32:42 raspberrypi kernel: [109697.123879] usb 2-1.3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jul 23 03:33:17 raspberrypi kernel: [109731.940235] usb 2-1.3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jul 23 03:34:02 raspberrypi kernel: [109776.996672] usb 2-1.3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jul 23 05:04:50 raspberrypi kernel: [115225.403375] usb 2-1.1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
Jul 23 05:04:55 raspberrypi kernel: [115230.523410] usb 2-1.1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
```

When mounting `/dev/nas/nas`, there is the following error in `dmesg`:

```
[ 2801.524342] EXT4-fs (dm-0): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[ 2801.745209] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
```

So, I unmounted the drive and ran e2fsck:

```
# e2fsck /dev/nas/nas
e2fsck 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
/dev/nas/nas contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/nas/nas: 10984163/366284800 files (0.4% non-contiguous), 921119327/2930259968 blocks
# e2fsck -p /dev/nas/nas
/dev/nas/nas: clean, 10984163/366284800 files, 921119327/2930259968 blocks
```

However, re-mounting the drive still yields an error in `dmesg`:

```
[ 4471.872335] usb 2-1.2: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 4471.894395] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x03 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=30s
[ 4471.894436] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: opcode=0x88 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 9f b7 48 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 4471.894454] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 10467144 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4845.700279] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
```

So... At this point I'm at a bit of a loss as to what the problem actually *is*. What can I do to fix this, short of completely swapping out the drive?

Comment: what USB->SATA device is it? (output of `lsusb` and `lsusb -t` )

Comment: @JaromandaX Added to the post.